# Varchar datatype in Jaydata

Tags: database, sqlite, jaydata

I am using Jaydata with sqlite.
I am defining database and their tables using Jaydata.
I want to use datatype nvarchar(20) but it generates Jaydata error though it is a sqlite datatype.

Kindly,suggest me the way in which i can use varchar/nvarchar using Jaydata.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite accepts a data type like `nvarchar(20)` but ignores most of it; the type is handled just as `TEXT`.
See the [data type documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Just use any text data type.